# Are there any online REST API sandbox/playground

Tags: rest, express, saas

I am looking for a quick way to spin up a very simple REST api, for testing purposes.

Specifically I want to be able to handle [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) requests (i.e need ability to handle the `OPTIONS` verb)

E.g: A service that spins up a temporary node instance with express and allows me to add request handlers and gives me a temporary url. Or the equivalent in another language (java, ruby, etc)

Comment: maybe try http://code.runnable.com/ ?

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for! add an answer to get credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try https://code.runnable.com it allows you to quickly build and run whole express apps and it allows multiple different languages not just node.js.